# How to get desired result in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have tables as shown below:

TABLE A:

```
ID    COLUMN1   COLUMN2  COLUMN3
-------------------------------
1      123      A12      INDIA
2      134      A12      INDIA
3      425      B124     UNITED STATES
4      500      B124     UNITED STATES
5      525      A12      AUSTRALIA
```

TABLE A is transformed into TABLE B, group by COLUMN2 and COLUMN3

TABLE B:

```
ID   COLUMN1    COLUMN2   COLUMN3
----------------------------------
1     123,134     A12     INDIA
2     425,500     B124    UNITED STATES
3     525         A12     AUSTRALIA
```

Now if values are updated in TABLE A for instance row 2 gets deleted.
TABLE A after update:

```
ID  COLUMN1   COLUMN2   COLUMN3
---------------------------------------
1   123        A12      INDIA
2   425        B124     UNITED STATES
3   500        B124     UNITED STATES
4   525        A12      AUSTRALIA
```

Now I have to update same on TABLE B to get below output, without truncating data.

```
ID  COLUMN1   COLUMN2   COLUMN3
-------------------------------------
1    123        A12     INDIA
2    425,500    B124    UNITED STATES
3    525        A12     AUSTRALIA
```

How do I get this output? As I cannot delete the row 1 in TABLE B, as the ID column should not be changed.

I've tried splitting delimited strings using XML.

Comment: You (possibly, difficult to say what you're asking for) want a trigger on table A that will recalculate the results for rows that are changed (I assume based on column3) and will update TableB with the newly calculated data. Alternatively, recreate tableB as a view of TableA using the SQL you originally used to transform it.

Comment: I am trying to write a SP for table B to be updated. As the updation for Table A is done using a SP.  @gbjbaanb

Comment: triggers will still work not matter how TableA is updated, Rip the code out of your SP, change insert to update, add a "where column3 = <the column3 for the row triggered>" and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

From the limited info, I think you want something along these lines using a [trigger](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/triggers.htm#LNPLS020):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER DEL_TABLEA_TRG
AFTER DELETE ON tableA
FOR EACH ROW
 BEGIN
  UPDATE tableB
  SET    column1=x, column2=y 
  WHERE  tableB.column3 = :old.tablea_column3;
 END DEL_TABLEA_TRG;
```

so every time a row is deleted on tableA, this fires, and updates the row on tableB with the new data that is read from tableA (you will have to use the appropriate SQL to do that)

You will have to create triggers for insert and update as well.

Alternatively, create a view that runs the SQL you originally used, this will give you something that looks like tableB and is always updated automatically (though performance might be an issue, depending on your usage)